# Font-size and device-pixel-ratio

Tags: css, media-queries, pixel-ratio

Let's say that I have default font size set to 16px (this should be redundant since it's default in most browsers):

For brevity, my site contains some box with size 10em x 10em.

```
body, html 
{
    font-size: 16px;
}
.box {
    border: 1px green solid;
    background-color:green;
    width:10em;
    height:10em;
}
```

My site is already responsive with `min-width` media queries for specific breakpoints targetted at em values (36, 62 and 85em).

The only thing my site does is change width and color of the box.

```
@media (min-width:36em) {
  .box {
    width: 36em;
    border:1px red solid;
    background-color:red;
  }
}
@media (min-width:62em) {
    .box {
        width: 62em;
        border:1px blue solid;
        background-color:blue;
    }
}
@media (min-width:85em) {
    .box {
        width: 85em;
        border:1px orange solid;
        background-color:orange;
    }
}
```

Now let's say that I have some device with resolution 1440x900 where browsers decide that the device's pixel density is 2dppx by default. As result, everything looks much bigger than it should be. And I don't like it.

But the solution should be easy, right? Just add a media query at start for 2dppx pixel density and since it's twice as much pixels, I just reduce the font size by half...that should work, right?

And since I use "em" on everything then by changing the font-size by half I automatically reduce size of everything "em"-sized by half...right?

```
@media ( min-resolution: 2dppx) {
    body, html {
        font-size: 50%;
    }
}
```

[relevant jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cb45g1j5/18/)

Well I found it does not work as I thought it would...I tried to google answers but did not find anything relevant, I suspect I misunderstand how font-sizes, ems and pixel density works...

- Reducing font-size by 50% reduces the font-size by much more than by half. The original size is 16px but font-size: 50%; results in a font much smaller than font-size:8px ... Tested in Firefox and Chrome. Does anyone know why is that?
- When I set font-size:8px; in the media query for 2dppx then media queries for min-width:36em, 62em and 85em do not trigger as I would have expected, at least when I change layout.css.devPixelsPerPx in Firefox. The min-width in media query behaves like the font-size is still at 16px eventhough it's changed with the dppx media query. Tested in Firefox and Chrome. Does anyone know why is that?

**UPDATE**

Looks like media queries are loaded in 1dppx context, it does not matter if you use "em", it seems they are cached on load and values such as min-width are fixed to the first value and eventhough you change the base font-size in different media query, other queries don't refresh.

The only solution I can think of right now is to multiply all media queries. One media query for px value in 1 dppx context and another media query for px value in 2 dppx context (which is 50% of the first value).

Comment: Why do you think that `font-size:50%` is half of `font-size:16px`? It is half of whatever the _parent font size_ is.

Comment: Anyway, reducing the font size at higher dppxs is not a good idea. Those screens have higher dppxs because the hardware dots are smaller. And if you set your font size to 16 hardware dots on a 2dppx screen, if will be the same size as 8 pixels on a standard (96dpi) monitor, which is _really really_ small. (It is to us old guys anyway.)

Comment: The parent is explicitly set to 16px (body,html) so 50% should equal to 8px. And I intend to reduce the size only for a specific resolution to target devices which use higher pixel density for no reason and the resulting page is bigger. I don't know any other way how to solve this problem other than targetting the specific density with specifi resolution.

Comment: No no, that's not how it works. If the default font size is 16px and `html` is set to 50%, then the font size for `html` is 8px. If `body`, being a child of `html`, is also set to 50%, then its font size becomes 4px.

Comment: @MrLister thank you, I did not notice that. It should have been a rule for html tag only, not for body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Mr Lister in comments, I found out that this:

```
@media ( min-resolution: 2dppx) {
    body, html {
        font-size: 50%;
    }
}
```

...is not what I intended to do. The 50% rule works for `<html>` tag AND for `<body>` tag. The resulting font size is not 8px in body, but 4px, because 50% in html is 8px and another 50% in nested body tag results in 4px.

What I intended to do was this:

```
@media ( min-resolution: 2dppx) {
    html {
        font-size: 50%;
    }
}
```

Font-size issue is solved.

For the media query: I found out that sizes in @media queries ignore pixel density but sizes in the CSS rule body do not. Since I use "em" sizes and SASS, I can simply replace all @media queries with this mixin (example with 2dppx):

```
@mixin media-min-width($min-width) {
    @media(min-width:$min-width), (min-width: $min-width / 2) and (min-resolution: 2dppx) {
        @content;
    }
}
```